# Splitting a string into 3 strings each with its own delimiter JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on code where i need to split a string into 3 different parts, each part would need its own delimiter to get the individual part out. I am not good with regex and the tutorials i have looked at dont really explain this well. So if you could push me in the right direction and if you have an answer explain each part of it that would be great!.

My input is

```
1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99
1 bottle of perfume at 18.99
1 packet of headache pills at 9.75
1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25
```

My desired output is to have 3 strings for each.

```
"1" "imported bottle of perfume" "27.99"
```

Code:

```
String pattern = "[(\\d)][(\\w)][(\\d)]";
String[] splits = data[i].split(pattern);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split on either whitespace preceded by digit or `at` string surrounded by whitespace. You would use [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that.

```
data[i].split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
```

`(?<=...)` is the syntax for look-behind. Similarly, `(?=...)` for look-ahead. Look-arounds are 0-length assertions. They just check if there is the pattern following or preceding a particular pattern or not.

So, `(?<=\\d)\\s+` will search for `\\s` which is preceded by a digit - `\\d`.

Comment: Rohit, can you please explain what does (?<=\\d) mean?

Comment: @MansoorShaikh. It's look-behind. You can go through the link which I have added.

Comment: Rohit great job at explaining each park to me i really appreciate that, that was what was most important to me so that way i knew what the heck it meant and could understand for future use. Appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

The easy way you can do is first split by "at" so now you have

```
"1 imported bottle of perfume" & "27.99"
```

so your first problem solved.

now about your next problem

what you can do just check first space  & then before space use parseInt. that all. may be this is easy tech. for understanding.